# How many buffers is enough in ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES::cBuffers?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

I'm working on a custom video transform filter derived from CTransformFilter. It doesn't do anything unusual in DirectShow terms such as extra internal buffering of media samples, queueing of output samples or dynamic format changes.

Graphs in graphedit containing two instance of my filters connected end to end (output of first connected to input of the second) hang when play is pressed. The graph definitely is *not* hanging within the ::Transform method override. The second filter instance is *not* connected directly to a video renderer.

The problem doesn't happen if a colour converter is inserted between the two filters. If I increase the number of buffers requested (ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES::cBuffers) from 1 to 3 then the problem goes away. The original DecideBufferSize override is below and is similar to lots of other sample DirectShow filter code.

What is a robust policy for setting the number of requested buffers in a DirectShow filter (transform or otherwise)? Is code that requests one buffer out of date for modern requirements? Is my problem too few buffers or is increasing the number of buffers masking a different problem?

```
    HRESULT MyFilter::DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator *pAlloc, ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *pProp)
{
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt;
    HRESULT hr = m_pOutput->ConnectionMediaType(&mt);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    BITMAPINFOHEADER * const pbmi = GetBitmapInfoHeader(mt);
    pProp->cbBuffer = DIBSIZE(*pbmi);
    if (pProp->cbAlign == 0) {
        pProp->cbAlign = 1;
    } 
    if (pProp->cBuffers == 0) {
        pProp->cBuffers = 3;
    }
    // Release the format block.
    FreeMediaType(mt);

    // Set allocator properties.
    ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES Actual;
    hr = pAlloc->SetProperties(pProp, &Actual);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    // Even when it succeeds, check the actual result.
    if (pProp->cbBuffer > Actual.cbBuffer) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific policy on amount of buffers, though you should definitely be aware that fixed number of buffers is the method to control sample rate. When all buffers are in use, a request for another buffer will block execution until such buffer is available.

That is, if your code is holding buffer references for certain purpose, you should allocate the respective amount so that you don't lock yourself. E.g. you hold last media sample reference internally, e.g. to be able to re-send it, and you still want to be able to deliver other media samples, so you need at least two buffers on the allocator.

Output pin is typically responsible to choose and set up the allocator, and input might might need to check and update properties if/when it is notified which allocator is to be used. On inplace transformation filters when you share the allocators, you might want an additional check in order to make sure the requirements are met.

- `DMO Wrapper Filter` uses (at least sometimes) allocators with one buffer only and is still in good standing
- with audio you normally have more buffers because you queue data for playback
- if you have a reference leak on your code and you don't release media sample pointers, then your streaming might lock dead because of this